# Getting php result in mysql

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I tried using this function to return a ***MySQL*** result in ***PHP***. I ran the *query* in ***PhpMyAdmin*** and it ran successfully. But when I try to run it in ***PHP***, nothing is returned.

My *table* is structured like this:

```html
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>Setting</td>
    <td>Value</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Setting</td>
    <td>stylesheet.css</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

**Function**:

```php
function getData()
{
require 'config.php';
$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
$sql = "SELECT Value FROM Settings WHERE Setting = 'Stylesheet'";
$result = mysql_query($con,$sql);
$row = mysql_result($result, 0);
mysqli_close($con);
return $row;
}
```

**Update**: *Still not working*

```
function getData()
{
require 'config.php';
$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);
$sql = "SELECT Value FROM Settings WHERE Setting = 'Stylesheet'";
$result = mysql_query($sql, $con);
$row = mysql_result($result, 0);
mysql_close($con);
return $row;
}
```

Comment: You're closing your connection before returning your `$row` - place it on top of `mysqli_close($con);` so that `mysqli_close($con);` is your last line.

Comment: please **print_r(getData());**  and show me result.Avoid require inside your function

Comment: @Fred-ii- that makes no difference. They've already stored the value returned by `mysql_result` into a local variable

Comment: @Fred-ii- no difference,if  he puts close statement after return ,this statement wouldn't execute and connection will not be closed

Comment: I'm confused about your table and column names. Could you clarify? Perhaps paste the output of `DESCRIBE tablename`

Comment: @Phil Ok, my mistake. I just did a quick test of my own and you're right.

Comment: Also, you must have been living under a rock for the last 5 years, otherwise you would know that the MySQL extension has been deprecated and is no longer supported. You should be using PDO or MySQLi instead.

Comment: Sorry, I was having trouble with using html tables. I'll get describe now.

Comment: shouldnt the mysql_query() function be `mysql_query($sql, $con);`? and to close shouldnt it be `mysql_close($con);`? edit:: i think that is why it isnt returning.. it isnt completing the function due to the syntax errors

Comment: @RyanHurling You have a point there, good catch.

Comment: the table name is Settings.

Comment: You are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`

Comment: thanks :) i made it into an answer so the OP has a better chance of noticing it

Comment: @RyanHurling Now it's the preverbial "Let's wait and see" ;-) However, if the OP has `mysqli` available, which most probably does, then all `mysql_` should be changed to `mysqli`, it's safer too.

Comment: @user2158870 Regarding your EDIT, `mysql_` is in the process of being deprecated/deleted. Try to change all `mysql_` to `mysqli` and try again. And check for syntax, letter case, etc.

Comment: Does mysqli_result work?  I tried that and it returned an error 500.

Comment: Have you tried what i proposed?

Comment: Yes. I edited my question to include the updated version.

Comment: @user2158870 Try `while($row = $result->fetch_row()) { $rows[]=$row;` instead of `$row = mysql_result($result, 0);` or `$row = $result->fetch_assoc()`

Comment: @user2158870 How are you using the `getData()` function?

Comment: mysqli_fetch_array worked! thanks

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't the `mysql_query()` function be `mysql_query($sql, $con);`?

And to close shouldn't it be `mysql_close($con);`?

**Edit:** i think that is reason why it isn't returning.. It isnt completing the function due to the syntax errors.

Answer (score 1):

You are mixing `mysql_*` and `mysqli_*`. You don't need to specify connection if there is only one for `mysql_*`.

```
Function [ <internal:mysql> function mysql_query ] {

  - Parameters [2] {
    Parameter #0 [ <required> $query ]
    Parameter #1 [ <optional> $link_identifier ]
  }
}
```

If you can't use e.g. **PDO**, consider refactoring your function:

```
require 'config.php';
$con = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password, $database);

function getData()
{
  $sql = "SELECT Value FROM Settings WHERE Setting = 'Stylesheet'";
  $result = mysql_query($sql);
  $row = mysql_result($result, 0);
  return $row;
}
```

Connection is closed at the end of request, you are just making unnecessary connect/disconnect actions.

Comment: I also mentioned something to the affect earlier, about the connection being closed, but that theory was quickly shot down.

Comment: @Fred-ii- You thought that nothing is returned because he closed connection before return, that's not true since the result is in `$row` and that's all it matters. I was trying to say that he only needs to connect to db once per request. `mysql_close` is not necessary since it's closed automatically (unless he specifically wants/have a reason).

Comment: Ok I understand, thanks for clearing that up. I misunderstood *"Connection is closed at the end of request, you are just making unnecessary connect/disconnect actions."* in your answer, that's why I said that.

Answer (score 0):

```
    class MySQL {
    var $ServerURL='localhost';
    var $ServerPort='3306';
    var $DataBaseName='test';
    var $DataBaseUser='root';
    var $DataBasePass='';
    public function __construct() {
        $this->mysqli = new mysqli($this->ServerURL,$this->DataBaseUser,$this->DataBasePass,$this->DataBaseName,$this->ServerPort);
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            printf('failed to connect');
            }
        else {
            }


    }

    }
    $MySQL = new MySQL;

       require 'config.php';
class Data extends MySQL {
     function getData()
        {
        $this->sql = "SELECT Value FROM Settings WHERE Setting = 'Stylesheet'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->mysqli, $this->sql);
        $this->row = mysql_result($this->result, 0);
        return $this->row;

        }
$Data = new Data;
```